# Retrive node data from firebase database

Tags: firebase, swift2, firebase-realtime-database

I have linked my app with a firebase database and i am wanting to retrieve the string of one node from it.

The node I am wanting to retrieve is shown below with the name of 'timeStamp'. Is there a way i can retrieve this text and then print it?[image: firebase node]

Comment: In the future, it's best practice to post your Firebase structure as text, not an image. That makes it searchable and helps us help you because we don't have to re-type the structure. You may also want to omit special characters in your node names.... user_information would be a good fit for this case.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is covered in the Firebase documentation guide

[Reading Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write)

and here's an example:

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
          .child("Users+infomation/ff..etc/timeStamp")
ref?.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
     let val = snapshot?.value
     print(val!)
})
```

*this is Swift 3